# Need help with word problem

Tags: word-problem

I am trying to solve this problem. Can someone please help me with the proper solution. My answer is "$2$ hours," but I want a step by step solution I can teach to my kid.

> **Problem:** A tiger eats a deer in $3$ hours and a bear takes $6$ hours to eat it. If they together eat it how much time will they take when tiger eats $2/3$ & beer eats $1/3$.

Comment: You already have the answer in the question. What is 2/3rd of 3 or 1/3rd of 6?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a step-by-step solution, consider this:

- The tiger takes $3$ hours to eat $1$ deer. This corresponds to "eating rate" of $\frac{3 \text{ hours}}{1 \text{ deer}}$.
- The bear takes $6$ hours for $1$ deer. This corresponds to "eating rate" of $\frac{6 \text{ hours}}{1 \text{ deer}}$.

Now, we know that the tiger needs to eat $\frac{2}{3}$ of a deer. This will take
$$
\require{cancel}
\require{xcancel}
\frac{2}{3} \text{ deer}\cdot\frac{3 \text{ hours}}{1 \text{ deer}} = \frac{2}{\xcancel 3} \xcancel{ \text{deer}}\cdot\frac{\xcancel{3} \text{ hours}}{1 \xcancel{\text{ deer}}} = 2 \text{ hours}
$$

For the bear, we know that it needs to eat $\frac{1}{3}$ of a deer. This will take
$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{1}{3} \text{ deer}\cdot\frac{6 \text{ hours}}{1 \text{ deer}} = \frac{1}{\xcancel 3} \xcancel{ \text{deer}}\cdot\frac{2\xcancel{3} \text{ hours}}{1 \xcancel{\text{ deer}}} = 2 \text{ hours}
$$
 Since they both take $2 \text{ hours}$ to eat there respective poritions, we can conclude that the total time will be $2 \text{ hours}$.

This technique of letting units guide you through a problem is known as [Dimensional Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis), which is a very useful to tool develop at a young age for solving problems.

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed, @Brian,  but your `$\xcancel$` is not rendering in some cases. I don't know how to fix it. Perhaps you might be able to.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for letting me know. I removed a `\require` statement just before I posted that I shouldn't have. Unfortunately, MathJax still rendered correctly for me until I closed the page. It should render properly now.